# ListView and Observable Collection memory leak?

Tags: listview, memory-leaks, windows-store-apps, observablecollection

I have a windows store app that is using a ListView with an item source of observable collection. I also use bindings and behaviors and commands inside of it.

I'm refreshing the Item source at periodic times. My problem is, it appears to be leaking. I suspect it has something to do with the Listview because when I remove it, memory is stable. Also, I checked and it seems mh collection is properly being disposed and recreated.

How can I fix this?

Thank you

Edit:

Just adding additional information. My code is something like this:

```
ObservableCollection<MyViewModel> myViewModels = new ObservableCollection<MyViewModel>();
```

Where MyViewModel is a class that is already inheriting **INotifyPropertyChanged**.

And then I use it in the ListView like this:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1"
      ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyButtonStyleSelector}"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=myViewModels}">

<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource Style_SelectorItem_Chromeless}" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="4" Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

With MyButtonStyleSelector selecting an ItemTemplate that is again binded to other properties of myViewModels (ex. Title, Description) and also have bindings to **RelayCommand** and **Behaviors**.

Edit 2:

When refreshing the data, I have a Clear() operation on my MyViewModel where it sets to null all of its child properties, as well as setting to null the myViewModels collection itself. However, when I check in VS Profiler, it seems that the MenuItemViewModels are not getting properly garbage collected (I don't see them in the items that have **negative item count)**. Is this because it is still being referenced in the ListView?

Edit 3:

This problem seems to be very close: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/761770/metro-apps-with-c-heavily-leaking-memory